# ¿la función mockjax no esta definida?

Tags: javascript, php, json

¿JSON no funciona en mockjax? la respuesta devuelve. TypeError no capturado: la función mockjax no está definida no se puede leer las variables ningún resultado, he estado intentando capturar algunos valores de json con mockjax y ajax desde un archivo php no puedo cargar ningun resultado debido a que la función mockjax no se puede ejecutar, los valores que trae la variable result son los alias de las consultas sql, **cargo y cantidad** lo ejecute en una consola y funcióna pero al llegar a la función mockjax lanza el error. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

```js
 <script>
  $(function() {
    var contenido;
    $.ajax({

      url: 'load.php',
      success: function(result) {
        var contenido = result;

        $("#resumen").html("");
        var sum = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

          var result = contenido[i];

          var cantidad = result.cantidad;

          var cargo = result.cargo;

          sum = sum + parseInt(result.cantidad);

          console.log(cantidad);

          console.log(cargo);

          var html = '<tr class= "tr"><td align="left" style="text-align: left;" ><span>' + result.cargo + '</span></td><td align="right"><span>' + result.cantidad + '</span></td></tr>';
          $("#resumen").append(html);
        }
        var htmlsum = '<tr class= "tr"><td align="left" style="text-align: left;" ><span><strong>Total</strong></span></td><td align="right"><span>' + sum + '</span></td></tr>';
        $("#resumen").append(htmlsum);
        $("#resumen").fadeIn();

        contenido = result;


        $.mockjax({
          url: '/orgchart/initdata',
          responseTime: 1000,
          contentType: 'application/json',
          responseText: contenido
        });

      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Si no está definida, es porque te falta agregar el [script de la librería](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-mockjax) y debe cargarse después de jQuery.

Comment: Le agregué la libreria ahora me marca otro error **length** no está definida, los alias cargo y cantidad están bien definidas

Comment: Antes de entrar al ciclo pon `console.log(result);` y edita la pregunta para agregar lo que aparece en la consola del navegador.